# Creating Game Menus

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am trying to create a menu for my soccer game. I have three panels which are under one panel. These four are all shown in one frame. I have used `CardLayout` to do this. You can switch from the first to the second panel, and from the second to the third panel. The third panel is where the game should run.The problem is: the first panel does not refresh to show player motion, it only shows the first frame. When I include a snippet in my code to refresh this window, my panel shows a white screen. If I comment it out, I can do the above operations. I need help on how I can solve this.

Here is the code:

```
public class GameRunner {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(g_szApplicationName);
    //game panels

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();
    JPanel teamSelect = new JPanel();

    JPanel gamePlay = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            gdi.StartDrawing(hdcBackBuffer);
            //fill our backbuffer with white
            gdi.fillRect(Color.WHITE, 0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
            SoccerPitchLock.lock();
            g_SoccerPitch.Render();
            SoccerPitchLock.unlock();
            gdi.StopDrawing(hdcBackBuffer);
            g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };

    //Buttons
    JButton exit = new JButton("EXIT");
    JButton cont = new JButton("CONTINUE");
    JButton startGame = new JButton("START GAME");
    JButton back = new JButton("BACK");
    //instance of the cardlayout
    CardLayout gr = new CardLayout();

    //Game Globals
    static String g_szApplicationName = "NHABVU";
    static SoccerPitch g_SoccerPitch;
    // bacause of game restart (g_SoccerPitch could be null for a while)
    static Lock SoccerPitchLock = new ReentrantLock();

    //create a timer
    static PrecisionTimer timer = new PrecisionTimer(Prm.FrameRate);

    //graphics
    static BufferedImage buffer;
    static Graphics2D hdcBackBuffer;

    //these hold the dimensions of the client window area
    static int cxClient;
    static int cyClient;

    public boolean gameOn = false;

    //constructor
    public GameRunner() throws InterruptedException {
        frame.setIconImage(LoadIcon("/SimpleSoccer/icon1.png"));
        buffer = new BufferedImage(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        hdcBackBuffer = buffer.createGraphics();

        //these hold the dimensions of the client window area
        cxClient = buffer.getWidth();
        cyClient = buffer.getHeight();

        //seed random number generator
        common.misc.utils.setSeed(0);

        Point center = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint();

        int y = center.y - frame.getHeight() / 2;
        frame.setLocation(center.x - frame.getWidth() / 2, y >= 0 ? y : 0);

        g_SoccerPitch = new SoccerPitch(cxClient, cyClient);

        //set other sizes of JPanels
        mainMenu.setSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
        teamSelect.setSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
        gamePlay.setSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);

        //setframe size
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WindowWidth, WindowHeight));

        gamePlay.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE: {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'r':
                    case 'R': {
                        SoccerPitchLock.lock();
                        g_SoccerPitch = null;
                        g_SoccerPitch = new SoccerPitch(cxClient, cyClient);
                        SoccerPitchLock.unlock();
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'p':
                    case 'P': {
                        g_SoccerPitch.TogglePause();
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'w':
                    case 'W':
                        gr.show(mainPanel, "2");
                        break;
                }//end switch
            }//end switch        
        });

        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            //has the user resized the client area?
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                //if so we need to update our variables so that any drawing
                //we do using cxClient and cyClient is scaled accordingly
                cxClient = e.getComponent().getBounds().width;
                cyClient = e.getComponent().getBounds().height;

                //now to resize the backbuffer accordingly.
                buffer = new BufferedImage(cxClient, cyClient, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                hdcBackBuffer = buffer.createGraphics();
            }
        });

        mainPanel.setLayout(gr);
        //add these to main menu
        mainMenu.add(cont, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainMenu.add(exit, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainMenu.setBackground(Color.blue);

        //add these to second mmenu
        teamSelect.add(startGame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        teamSelect.add(back, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        teamSelect.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        mainPanel.add(mainMenu, "1");
        mainPanel.add(teamSelect, "2");
        mainPanel.add(gamePlay, "3");

        //inbuilt method to show panels
        gr.show(mainPanel, "1");

        //action listeners for buttons
        cont.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v) {
                gr.show(mainPanel, "2");
                gameOn = true;
            }
        });

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v) {
                gr.show(mainPanel, "1");
                gameOn = true;
            }
        });

        startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v) {
                gr.show(mainPanel, "3");
                gameOn = true;
            }
        });

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer.Start();

        while (true) {
            //update
            if (timer.ReadyForNextFrame()) {
                System.out.println("ANDREW");
                SoccerPitchLock.lock();
                g_SoccerPitch.Update();
                SoccerPitchLock.unlock();

                //render
                gamePlay.repaint();

                try {
                    //System.out.println(timer.TimeElapsed());
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }//end while
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new GameRunner();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(GameRunner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay guys i have decided to use a different concept.I have used frame hiding to create my menu whereby selecting a certain actionlistener will make a certain frame visible and the others not.the problem here is where should i call the update segment code so that the game wont start updating itself before i go to the gameplay menu here is the code

```
public class Main {
 //--------------------------------- Globals ------------------------------
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

static String g_szApplicationName = "NHABVU";
//static String g_szWindowClassName = "MyWindowClass";
static SoccerPitch g_SoccerPitch;
// bacause of game restart (g_SoccerPitch could be null for a while)
static Lock SoccerPitchLock = new ReentrantLock();
//create a timer
static PrecisionTimer timer = new PrecisionTimer(Prm.FrameRate);

//static UserControlledTeam UserTeam = new UserControlledTeam(g_SoccerPitch.m_pRedTeam);


static BufferedImage buffer;
static Graphics2D hdcBackBuffer;
//these hold the dimensions of the client window area
static int cxClient;
static int cyClient;
static boolean gameOn;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    //code segment for the first panel/the first panelm that is displayed
    final Window MainMenu = new Window(g_szApplicationName);
    MainMenu.setIconImage(LoadIcon("/SimpleSoccer/icon1.png"));
    MainMenu.setResizable(false);
    JPanel MainMenuPanel = new JPanel();
    //create buttons for main menu
    JButton Exit = new JButton("EXIT");
    JButton Continue = new JButton("CONTINUE");
    //add these buttons to the mainmenupanel
    MainMenuPanel.add(Continue);
    MainMenuPanel.add(Exit);

    //code segment for the team select panel
  //code segment for the first panel/the first panelm that is displayed
    final Window TeamMenu = new Window(g_szApplicationName);
    TeamMenu.setIconImage(LoadIcon("/SimpleSoccer/icon1.png"));
    TeamMenu.setResizable(false);
    JPanel TeamMenuPanel = new JPanel();
    //create buttons for main menu
    JButton StartGame = new JButton("PLAY");
    JButton Back = new JButton("BACK");
    JComboBox TeamSelect = new JComboBox();
     String[] teams = {"Choose team...", "HIGHLANDERS", "DYNAMOS"};
    TeamSelect.addItem(teams[0]);
    TeamSelect.addItem(teams[1]);
    TeamSelect.addItem(teams[2]);
    //add these buttons to the mainmenupanel
    //StartGame.setEnabled(false);
    TeamMenuPanel.add(TeamSelect);
    TeamMenuPanel.add(StartGame);
    TeamMenuPanel.add(Back);

    /*
     * game window
     * this is where the game will be played
     */
    final Window window = new Window(g_szApplicationName);
    window.setIconImage(LoadIcon("/SimpleSoccer/icon1.png"));
    buffer = new BufferedImage(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    hdcBackBuffer = buffer.createGraphics();
    //these hold the dimensions of the client window area
    cxClient = buffer.getWidth();
    cyClient = buffer.getHeight();
    //seed random number generator
    common.misc.utils.setSeed(0);

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Point center = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint();
    //Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    window.setResizable(false);
    //set window locations
    int y = center.y - window.getHeight() / 2;
    //setlocation of main window
    window.setLocation(center.x - window.getWidth() / 2, y >= 0 ? y : 0);
    //set location of main menu window
    MainMenu.setLocation(center.x - window.getWidth() / 2, y >= 0 ? y : 0);
    //set location for teaam select menu
    TeamMenu.setLocation(center.x - window.getWidth() / 2, y >= 0 ? y : 0);



    g_SoccerPitch = new SoccerPitch(cxClient, cyClient);


    final JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            gdi.StartDrawing(hdcBackBuffer);
            //fill our backbuffer with white
            gdi.fillRect(Color.WHITE, 0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
            SoccerPitchLock.lock();
            g_SoccerPitch.Render();
            SoccerPitchLock.unlock();
            gdi.StopDrawing(hdcBackBuffer);
            g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };
    //panel configurations
    panel.setSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WindowWidth, WindowHeight));
    window.add(panel);
    window.pack();

    //MainMenuPanelConfigurations
    MainMenuPanel.setSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    MainMenuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WindowWidth, WindowHeight));
    MainMenu.add(MainMenuPanel);
    MainMenu.pack();

  //TeamMenuPanelConfigurations
    TeamMenuPanel.setSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    TeamMenuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WindowWidth, WindowHeight));
    TeamMenu.add(TeamMenuPanel);
    TeamMenu.pack();

    //add keylistener to window frame
    window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE: {

                        System.exit(0);

                }
                break;
                case 'r':
                case 'R': {
                    SoccerPitchLock.lock();
                    g_SoccerPitch = null;
                    g_SoccerPitch = new SoccerPitch(cxClient, cyClient);
                    SoccerPitchLock.unlock();
                }
                break;

                case 'p':
                case 'P': {
                    g_SoccerPitch.TogglePause();
                }
                break;      
            }//end switch
        }//end switch        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if(g_SoccerPitch.GameOn() && g_SoccerPitch != null){

            switch (e.getKeyChar()) {

                case 'w':
                case 'W':{
                    System.out.println("W IS PRESSED");

                    //if player is within ballkickingrange kick the ball up
                    //if yu're at target switch off ball chasing
                    if( g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinReceivingRange()){ 
                        g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveUp();

                        g_SoccerPitch.Ball().Kick(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().ballPos, 1.5 );
                    }
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOn();
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SetTarget(g_SoccerPitch.Ball().m_vPosition);
                    if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().AtTarget()){
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOff();
                    }
                }
                break;

                case 's':
                case 'S':{
                    System.out.println("S IS PRESSED");

                    //if player is within ballkickingrange kick the ball down
                    //if yu're at target switch off ball chasing
                    if( g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinReceivingRange()){ 

                        g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveDown();
                        g_SoccerPitch.Ball().Kick(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().ballPos, 1.5 );
                    }
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOn();
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SetTarget(g_SoccerPitch.Ball().m_vPosition);
                    if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().AtTarget()){
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOff();
                    }
                }
                break;

                case 'a':
                case 'A':{
                    System.out.println("A IS PRESSED");

                    //if player is within ballkickingrange kick the ball up
                    //if yu're at target switch off ball chasing
                    if( g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinReceivingRange()){ 
                        g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveLeft();
                        g_SoccerPitch.Ball().Kick(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().ballPos, 1.5 );
                    }
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOn();
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SetTarget(g_SoccerPitch.Ball().m_vPosition);
                    if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().AtTarget()){
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOff();
                    }
                }
                break;

                case 'd':
                case 'D':{
                    System.out.println("D IS PRESSED");

                    //if player is within ballkickingrange kick the ball up
                    //if yu're at target switch off ball chasing
                    if( g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinKickingRange()){ 
                        g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveRight();
                        g_SoccerPitch.Ball().Kick(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().ballPos, 1.5 );
                    }
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOn();
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SetTarget(g_SoccerPitch.Ball().m_vPosition);
                    if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().AtTarget()){
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOff();
                    }
                }
                break;

                case 'm':
                case 'M':{

                     if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.InControl() && g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinReceivingRange()){
                      System.out.println("M IS PRESSED");
                      g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().UserPlayerShootBall();
                     }   
                }
                break;

                case 'l':
                case 'L':{

                     if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.InControl()){
                      System.out.println("L IS PRESSED");
                      if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinReceivingRange()){
                      g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().UserPlayerPassBall();
                      }
                        }  else{
                         System.out.println("Marking The Ball");
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOn();
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SetTarget(g_SoccerPitch.Ball().m_vPosition);
                    if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().AtTarget()){
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOff();
                    }
                     } 
                }
                break;

            }//end switch
        }//end switch  
        }//closes if



    });

    window.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override //has the user resized the client area?
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            //if so we need to update our variables so that any drawing
            //we do using cxClient and cyClient is scaled accordingly
            cxClient = e.getComponent().getBounds().width;
            cyClient = e.getComponent().getBounds().height;
            //now to resize the backbuffer accordingly. 
            buffer = new BufferedImage(cxClient, cyClient, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            hdcBackBuffer = buffer.createGraphics();
        }
    });

    //make the mainmenu visible when you start the game
    MainMenu.setVisible(true);

    //add actionlisteners
    Continue.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v){
          window.setVisible(false);
          MainMenu.setVisible(false);
          TeamMenu.setVisible(true);
          g_SoccerPitch.SetGameOff();
        }
        });

    Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v){
          System.exit(0);
        }
        });
    StartGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v){
          window.setVisible(true);
          MainMenu.setVisible(false);
          TeamMenu.setVisible(false);
          //gameOn=true;
          g_SoccerPitch.SetGameOff();

        }
        });
    Back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v){
          window.setVisible(false);
          MainMenu.setVisible(true);
          TeamMenu.setVisible(false);
          gameOn=false;
        }
        });

    TeamSelect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String selected = (String)TeamSelect.getSelectedItem();
            if (selected.equals("HIGHLANDERS")) {
                g_SoccerPitch.setUserControlledTeam(g_SoccerPitch.m_pRedTeam);
                g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.setToBeUserControlledTeam(true);
            } else if (selected.equals("DYNAMOS")) {

                g_SoccerPitch.setUserControlledTeam(g_SoccerPitch.m_pBlueTeam);
                g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.setToBeUserControlledTeam(true);

            }
        }
    });

    timer.Start();

    while (true) {
        //update
        if (timer.ReadyForNextFrame()) {
            SoccerPitchLock.lock();
            g_SoccerPitch.Update();
            SoccerPitchLock.unlock();
            //render
            //panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();

            try {
                //System.out.println(timer.TimeElapsed());
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }//end while


}
```

}